# Conver the result of a for loop to a table

Tags: powershell, for-loop, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I can't convert the following for loop to a table:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++) 
{ 
    $ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue' 
    Write-Progress -PercentComplete ((100*$i)/255) -Activity "Gathering IP's"  

    nslookup("192.168.2." + $i) | Format-Table
}
```

The only thing that happens is that for every adress that is not reachable, it shows the router name/ip:

```
Server:  easy.box.local
Address:  192.168.2.1

Name:    easy.box.local
Address:  192.168.2.1

Server:  easy.box.local
Address:  192.168.2.1
```

I want to sort it like a table to make it more convinient and more viewable

Comment: For a different approach, try "Get-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.2.*  | Format-Table"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a Windows 8 or later machine you could use [System.Net.Dns]::Resolve (Note that unsuccessful lookups will have the IP address as the hostname)

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++) { 
    Write-Progress -PercentComplete ((100*$i)/255) -Activity "Gathering IP's"  
    [System.Net.Dns]::Resolve("192.168.2." + $i) | Select HostName,AddressList
}
```

Comment: This is actually pretty neat! thanks a lot for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You could use *regex* to grab the information and create a new object which will make it sortable:

```
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue' 
for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++) 
{ 
    Write-Progress -PercentComplete ((100*$i)/255) -Activity "Gathering IP's"  

    $nsLookupResult = nslookup("192.168.2." + $i)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Server = [regex]::Match($nsLookupResult,'Server:\s+(\S+)').Groups[1].Value
        Address = [regex]::Match($nsLookupResult,'Address:\s+(\S+)').Groups[1].Value
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Server           Address        
------           -------        
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
easy.box.loca 192.168.150.254
```

**Note:** There might be a builtin PowerShell cmdlet which would make this obsolete.

**Note 2:** You only have to set the `$ErrorActionPreference` once thats why I set it outside the for loop.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but if you test your script you will notice that it will always output the same ip regardles if the lookup was successful or not

Comment: Thats the Output from nslookup